# Weird "jobs" behavior within zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, jobs

I am getting weird behavior with the `jobs`, `fg` and `bg` commands in my zsh shell. Here is an example (this happens for all commands, not just `python`):

```
$ python &
[1] 21214
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:02:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[1]  + 21214 suspended (tty output)  python
$ jobs
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  python
$ fg 1
fg: job not found: 1
$ bg 1
bg: job not found: 1
```

I am using the standard oh-my-zsh installation on OS X.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You may be used to `fg N` (where N is a job number) working in Bash. But it’s a little different in Zsh, requiring a `%`; e.g., `fg %1`. The Bash behavior is convenient, so you can make Zsh do the same:

```
fg() {
    if [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 = - ]]; then
        builtin fg %-
    else
        builtin fg %"$@"
    fi
}
```

The same can be done for `bg` and `history`. This was originally from [this thread](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg01243.html).

You can also just type `fg` and the `%1` is implied.  Tab-completion is great for this too when you have a few jobs going: `fg<tab>`

Comment: Or learn the *real* short way: just type `%1`.The `fg` is assumed.

Comment: I thought zsh was a strict superset of bash. How come this behavior isn't the same?

Comment: Zsh is not a strict superset of Bash: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html

Comment: @BenSandler I love and accept zsh way, but, it's not the same though lol~ changing habit is quite sensitive.